# Get status of forever app or pm2 app

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2, forever

I am currently using [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) but am considering switching to [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) because forever does not provide a status option.

I cannot do:

```
forever status myApp
```

To determine if my app is running or not I must do:

```
forever list | grep -i myApp
```

And even with this it is unreliable because myApp might be listed in a stopped state (I appreciate you could come up with some ugly grep solution to accomodate but I want something natural).

With pm2 the docs say you can do:

```
pm2 show myApp # Show all informations about application
```

pm2 seems far more natural.

Any thoughts on how to get app status using forever without grepping the forever list?

How does pm2 compare regarding getting app status?

Comment: yes by status you mean the process status like stopped, errored or running? this can be seen using pm2 list this will print all the processes status

Comment: 4 years later, I would only ever use forever for extremely lightweight work, pm2 wins hands down out of these 2 libs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forever cannot do this without using `forever list`.

pm2 can and `pm2 show` works great with expected exit codes.

I tried pm2 for this sole reason and found it much better than Forever. It does everything Forever does but (unbelievable but true) even simpler than Forever.

The commands are the same with more.

Example:

```
forever start app.js

pm2 start app.js --name "api" // built in pidfile management here

pm2 start app.js -i 0 --name "api" // load balance your app on all cores! WOW!

pm2 list // same as forever list

pm2 show api // returns 0 or 1 return code as expected

pm2 restart api // if running on multiple cores, restarts all associated processes
```

Forever is dead, pm2 is the new king! PM2 forever!

No need for reboot crontab entries. pm2 handles that with:

```
pm2 startup

pm2 save
```

Done!